# UICollectionView imageview performance

Tags: ios, multithreading, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create a collection view that just shows images that I have cached on my device. Here is the code I used to get it from the cache:

```
-(void)loadImagesFromCache { //only runs on a background thread
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"IMAGES%@", _eventID];
    NSMutableArray *photoInfoArray = [[PhotoUtil loadArrayForPath:path] mutableCopy];
    if (!photoInfoArray || photoInfoArray.count == 0) {
        return;
    }
    NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:photoInfoArray.count];
    for (NSDictionary *photoInfoDict in photoInfoArray) {
        PhotoInfo *photoInfo = [[PhotoInfo alloc] initWithDictionary:photoInfoDict];
        UIImage *image = [PhotoUtil getImageForPath:[photoInfo photoPath]];
        [images addObject:image];
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        _allPhotos = images;
        [_collectionView reloadData];
        [_refreshControl endRefreshing];
    });
}
```

And this is the cell for indexPath method:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"PhotoCell";

    PhotoCell *cell = (PhotoCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.imageView setBackgroundColor:[PhotoStyleSheet getBlueColor]];
    cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = [[PhotoStyleSheet getBlueColor] CGColor];
    cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        UIImage *image = _allPhotos[indexPath.row];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [cell.imageView setImage:image];
        });
    });
    return cell;
}
```

Whenever the images first load, not only is the order jumbled up for a moment (it does eventually right itself) but the collection view is unscrollable between the moments when the image views turn blue, and the images load. I am clearly doing something processor intensive on the main thread, and I think it's in the cell for indexPath method, but nothing I'm doing is working. Help?

Comment: You should only build a `NSMutableArray` of `NSString` filepaths outside of `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, then do all the loading of the image and such in that method, I think...

Comment: isn't that what i'm doing? I build the array of filepaths in another method, and then, when i have a handle on it, i reload the data of the collection view using pointers in that array.

Comment: No.  You've built an array `_allPhotos` of `UIImage`... which is an image, not a filepath.  And you're using this array in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` rather than the array of file paths.